# Craft wording regarding what's on and off-topic for the tour page

Tags: discussion, tour

The section regarding what kinds of questions are suitable or not on the site on our [tour page](https://security.stackexchange.com/tour) (formerly known as /about) only contains generic wording derived from the site description:

> Ask about...
>
> - Specific issues regarding the protection of assets from threats and vulnerabilities
> - Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered
>
> Don't ask about...
>
> - Anything not directly related to Information security
> - Questions that are primarily opinion-based
> - Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer

We should update this to cover the most common issues. The “ask about” list should be a summary of what we have in the [help/on-topic page](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (the old /faq#on-topic). The “don't ask about” list should cover our commonly-used close reasons (e.g. a line to refer to SU/SF/U&L/… for questions like “how do I configure my firewall”).

This is a call for wording proposals. Please keep in mind that the lists should remain manageable — 3—4 items tops. They don't have to be lists (only the leading “(don't) ask about” text is imposed), but that's usually an effective format.